# Easy Install of Node js package on without publishing

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a way to deploy a node js app to multiple machines locally.

Is there some way to create a batch file to zip, or installer file, that will put my node js application and all its dependencies, and possibly get node js too easily on multiple machines by sending one or more files to install?

Also, is there some way to provide updates if the code is updated to all these machines?

Basically, I want to be able to install my node js package/application on multiple locations locally without having to publish my work to npm. Any ideas? cant seem to find anything out there except for putting node js on a web server, or publishing to npm?

Comment: If you can share a drive with all of the computers, you can install it to a central location and use that. On publishing to npm, note that you can 1) setup your own registry, 2) install from a (private or public) Git repository, or 3) `npm i --save file:///path/to/central/package`

Comment: @Whymarrh Installing to a shared network location is just asking for problems.  It's introducing a single point of failure.  Additionally, there might be multiple architectures involved, so `npm rebuild` is going to be required when deploying.

Comment: The problem with me sending the file with the package.json and installing that package from a file path, is that I have other modules I have created in the node_modules folder that are not published on npm and that I want to keep private as well... I guess I could use inno installer to create an install file but then i guess theyd have to uninstall and reinstall everytime I sent an updated install file. Also trying to think of a solution using batch file...

Answer (score 0):

This is quite vast. Without using advanced tools these two could work :

```
git pull origin master
npm install
```

or a solution with `rsync`

Answer (score 0):

> node js application and all its dependencies

Run an `npm install` where you're developing your application.  Then, just tarball the whole thing, including the `node_modules` directory.  When you deploy your tarball to another machine, be sure to run `npm rebuild` so that any binary dependencies are built for the platform you just deployed to.  If you do your initial `npm install` on the same platform type, you can usually skip the rebuild step.

> Also, is there some way to provide updates if the code is updated to all these machines?

There are an infinite number of ways, and what you pick depends on your needs.  You could check-in your whole project including `node_modules` to version control and just have a Bash script regularly pull from a branch and bounce things as necessary for your specific needs.  Beware though that `node_modules` tends to be huge... it's usually left out of version control.  Perhaps stick to the tarball on a server and pull that as necessary.

> and possibly get node js too

Keep that separate.  You don't need to deploy Node.js every time you deploy your application.